# Segmentation fault: 11 when importing math into Python

Tags: python, python-3.3

It crashes everytime I try to import from math. Is there a way to reinstall the math library? I'm on Python 3.3.2.

```
sidwyn$ python3
>>> from math import pi
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: `math` is a built-in module, I would suggest reinstalling Python, not just that module.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling python3, restarting, but nothing seems to solve it.

Comment: How are you installing, and which platform are you on?

Comment: Running the OS X installer from http://www.python.org/download/.

Comment: Double check the architecture or try installing from source.

Comment: What happens if you just `import math`?  What's on your `PYTHONPATH`?  Any other modules called `math`?

Comment: 1. import math and printing pi causes a segmentation fault. 
2.`PYTHONPATH` is empty 3. No other modules called math.

Comment: Try to see if output of `import math; math.__file__` points to the right location.

Comment: You should try printing out a more useful traceback with Python's faulthandler: http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#faulthandler

Comment: @cababunga: It does point correctly. Also, I realized that in 90% of cases writing a code in the second line causes it to crash. E.g. any second line of Python code would crash the program.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: With the fault handler, it prints out nothing much more:
`Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007fff7274b310:
Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: Can you run it in a debugger to get a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a Mavericks issue. Should have searched more thoroughly before asking. Sorry.

Duplicate Question: [Python crashing when running two commands (Segmentation Fault: 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158381/python-crashing-when-running-two-commands)

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue18458

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
$ env -i python3.3
>>> import faulthandler
>>> faulthandler.enable()
>>> import math
>>> math
<module 'math' (built-in)>
>>> from math import pi
# should segfault
```

and try to run python inside the GNU debugger. You have to type "run" into the gdb shell to start Python and "backtrace" to get the C call stack.

```
$ gdb python3.3
(gdb) run
>>> from math import pi
# should segfault
(gdb) backtrace
```

and post the output here.