# Segmentation fault: 11 while using boost mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking

I implemented a lock macro based on boost mutex, the code is below:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define LOCK(x) if(Lock _lock_=x){}else

class Mutex{
public:
    friend class Lock;

private:
    boost::mutex mutex_;

    void Lock(){
        mutex_.lock();
    };

    void Unlock(){
        mutex_.unlock();
    };
};

class Lock{
public:
    Lock(Mutex& mutex):mutex_(mutex){mutex_.Lock();};
    ~Lock(){mutex_.Unlock();};

    operator bool() const {
        return false;
    }

private:
    Mutex& mutex_;
};

void wait(int seconds)
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(seconds));
}

Mutex mtx;

void thread()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        LOCK(mtx){
            wait(1);
            std::cout << "Thread " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread t1(thread);
    boost::thread t2(thread);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

I compiled it in the Mac OS using `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ lock_raii.cc -lboost_system -lboost_thread`. When I run it, there is a `Segmentation fault: 11`.

What's the problem with it?

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Please don't use that macro. It's ugly.

Comment: C++11 provides standard mutex and locking constructs; see [lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard). Your macro trick is clever, but not good practice. It adds another layer of indirection and cognitive friction for virtually no gain.

Comment: Sorry, i ment this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158381/python-crashing-when-running-two-commands

Comment: Is there any reason for you not to use lock_guard from either C++11 or boost? I find that macro "trick" particularly nasty...

Comment: Why are you reinventing a mutex when you have `boost::mutex`? Why are you reinventing a lock type when you have `boost::scoped_lock`?  If you really want to make that macro work (which is a bad idea IMHO) then you need to make the `Lock` type movable (not copyable) and make it not unlock anything in the destructor if ownership of the lock has moved to another object, then you're guaranteed only one object owns the lock and only one will unlock it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside of the fact that this method at least questionable, I do not see a problem with the code. gcc v4.7.0 on Linux does not have issues either (there is no segmentation fault). So you may not setup boost properly or have a bug somewhere. You should run your program under debugger and see where the problem occurs. 
In theory this code:

```
if(Lock _lock_=x){}else
```

could be compiled as:

```
if(Lock _lock_= Lock(x) ){}else
```

and invoking copy ctor and have double unlock on the mutex. To make sure this is not the issue make copy ctor for class Lock private.

Comment: If you make the copy constructor private then `Lock _lock_=x` is ill-formed and will not compile. In short, the design is broken, the solution is to change it.