# Segfault 11 with pandas with Python v2.7.6 RC1 on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, osx-mavericks

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: path = 'ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'

In [3]: from pandas import DataFrame, Series;

In [4]: records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]

In [5]: frame = DataFrame(records)

In [6]: frame['tz'][:10]
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Any access to frame results in a segfault. I have already upgraded to Python 2.7.6 RC1. Also happened in 2.7.5, also happens outside ipython. What am I to do?

Comment: How big is the `usagov` data? Could you make a smaller version of it that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: This is a tutorial in a book. That is not the issue, the data is not big. The data is visible here: https://github.com/pydata/pydata-book/blob/master/ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt

Comment: Can't reproduce on Mac OS 10.7.5, Python 2.7.3.

Comment: This is a mavericks specific issue, OS X 10.9 :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531969/segmentation-fault-11-in-os-x

Comment: This does not appear to be related to the 10.9 readline segfault problem noted in the other question. Most likely it has something to do with how pandas or numpy or some other package used by pandas was built and installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Numpy that has been fixed recently.  See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3962