# Segfault on join for python 2.7.4 on osx - correct behaviour or bug?

Tags: python, macos

I'm experiencing the following:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.4 (v2.7.4:026ee0057e2d, Apr  6 2013, 11:43:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ','.join(['1','2','3']
... 
... 
... )
Segmentation fault: 11

$ python
Python 2.7.4 (v2.7.4:026ee0057e2d, Apr  6 2013, 11:43:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ','.join(['1','2','3'])
'1,2,3'
>>> ','.join(['1','2','3']
Segmentation fault: 11

$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

This looks like an interpreter bug to me, am I right?

---

(My instinct says I should be getting a

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

)

Comment: looks like (another) osx bug. probably related http://stackoverflow.com/a/19629468/1265154

Comment: Which version of OS X is that? Is this the version of Python that comes with OS X?

Comment: @uselpa mavericks. i upgraded - never messed around with the python version, so it's whatever osx wanted me to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW; this is my setup of Mavericks. As you see all my binaries are in `/System/Library/...` and not `/Library/...`. Try to run one of these directly if you have them.

There are several ways to choose your current Python version (`python-config`, see also `man python`), maybe you have interfered with those?

```
pu@pumbair: ~  which python
/usr/bin/python
pu@pumbair: ~  v /usr/bin/pytho*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    57K 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel   925B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    82B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/python2.5-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    82B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    82B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    57K 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/pythonw2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76B 27 Oct 20:28 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

Comment: ooooh... this is probably an upgrade snafu. i also have the versions you list, and they're properly compiled. i haven't messed around with my python versions, but i think i have an explicit path directive somewhere, and it's pointing to an old location for python (i wonder how old...)