# Python 2.7 crashing when installing requests module on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

> $ ./easy_install --index-url=http://pypiserver.test.net:8081/simple requests
>   Searching for requests
>   Reading pypiserver.test.net:8081/simple/requests/
>   Best match: requests 2.2.1
>   Downloading pypiserver.test.net:8081/packages/requests-2.2.1.tar.gz
>   Processing requests-2.2.1.tar.gz
>   Writing /var/folders/cn/fs0bhsg14k73_tj4g81yh5sw000d4g/T/easy_install-ONrhgU/requests-2.2.1/setup.cfg
>   Running requests-2.2.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders  /cn/fs0bhsg14k73_tj4g81yh5sw000d4g/T/easy_install-ONrhgU/requests-2.2.1/egg-dist-tmp-iC7PX9
>   **Segmentation fault: 11**

UPDATE:  I think it the way I built Python as if I just downloaded the python2.7.6 built version, requests module installed fine.  I do need to build python though as that is part of our release process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault: 11 in OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531969/segmentation-fault-11-in-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

I run

```
pip install requests
```

that works fine:

```
$ pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Downloading requests-2.2.1.tar.gz (421kB): 421kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

Installing collected packages: requests
  Running setup.py install for requests

Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: **pip fails too:**  
$ pip install requests
  
Downloading/unpacking requests  
  Downloading requests-2.2.1.tar.gz (421kB): 421kB downloaded  
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests  
Cleaning up…  
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code -11 in   /private/var/folders/cn/fs0bhsg14k73_tj4g81yh5sw000d4g/T/pip_build_spatterson/requests  
Storing complete log in /Users/spatterson/.pip/pip.log

Comment: @coolstang101 ah, oh, its a segfault. you need to update python.