# Why do I get a segmentation fault when using modulo in the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, interpreter, modulo

```
MacBook-Air:~ sgarza62$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1 % 10
1
>>> 10 % 1
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Also happens with modulo operations such as `1 % 1` and `2 % 2`.

*Running Mac OS 10.9.2 on this machine.*

Comment: This seems to be OS (or build) specific. Just for reference: it works fine on python2.7 [GCC 4.8.1] on linux2.

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531969/segmentation-fault-11-in-os-x

Comment: @Hyperboreus Ah, you're right. I hadn't realized it was invariably seg faulting on the second command. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the modulo operation. The interactive interpreter will crash on every **2nd** command invoked.

The OS 10.9 (Mavericks) upgrade caused instability in some Python releases. To fix this specific issue, download and run the patch through the Terminal:

```
>>> curl -O http://bugs.python.org/file32324/patch_readline_issue_18458.sh
>>> openssl sha1 patch_readline_issue_18458.sh
>>> sh ./patch_readline_issue_18458.sh
```

Newer Python releases have fixed the problems introduced with Mavericks. Better to install the latest version at https://www.python.org/downloads/

*Thanks to [Hyperboreus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/763505/hyperboreus) for finding the solution in the question comments.*