# Need help understanding Mac OS crash report

Tags: python, macos, crash-reports

I'm developing a GUI app in python, and packaging it with pyinstaller. On a different machine, the app keeps crashing with the following crash report (I removed the middle chunk). I have no experience with crash logs, and would appreciate any help on how to proceed with this.

```
Process:         test [9701]
Path:            /Users/USER/Desktop/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
Identifier:      test
Version:         0.0.0 (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [9698]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2014-06-09 17:13:40.558 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
Report Version:  10

Crashes Since Last Report:           1
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      D034FFD8-9A64-DFC6-DC85-9FD7B4DD8F61

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a40cd46 __kill + 10
1   test                            0x000000010f924c18 0x10f922000 + 11288
2   test                            0x000000010f937bed 0x10f922000 + 89069
3   test                            0x000000010f923454 0x10f922000 + 5204

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a40d6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91036f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91036ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91021191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a40dd16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92b67dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92b679ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a40d6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91036f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91036ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91021191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000001  rcx: 0x00007fff502dcf28  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
rdi: 0x00000000000025e5  rsi: 0x000000000000000b  rbp: 0x00007fff502dcf80  rsp: 0x00007fff502dcf28
r8: 0x0000000000000003   r9: 0x0000000035447f8c  r10: 0x00000000000fc080  r11: 0x0000000000000206
r12: 0x00007fff502ddd00  r13: 0x00007fa5d2c0e920  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000001
rip: 0x00007fff8a40cd46  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fa5d2c0f9a0
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
   0x10f922000 -        0x10f93eff7 +test (0.0.0 - ???) <C371E49E-CC99-3791-8965-4D3EE55AD3BF> /Users/USER/Desktop/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
0x7fff6f522000 -     0x7fff6f55693f  dyld (210.2.3) <6900F2BA-DB48-3B78-B668-58FC0CF6BCB8> /usr/lib/dyld
0x7fff89c71000 -     0x7fff89dc3fff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.9.2 - 1.9.2) <DC5F3D1B-036A-37DE-BC24-7636DC95EA1C> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x7fff89dc4000 -     0x7fff89e89ff7  com.apple.coreui (2.0 - 181.1) <83D2C92D-6842-3C9D-9289-39D5B4554C3A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x7fff89e8a000 -     0x7fff8a15bfff  com.apple.security (7.0 - 55179.16.1) <49A6A8FD-124D-30E0-94C3-C73F8C9469E6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x7fff8a335000 -     0x7fff8a35dfff  libJPEG.dylib (852) <4E159C31-1B41-3EFF-89EC-3F7BC9053F2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x7fff8a3be000 -     0x7fff8a3c4fff  libmacho.dylib (829) <BF332AD9-E89F-387E-92A4-6E1AB74BD4D9> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x7fff8a3c5000 -     0x7fff8a3e5fff  libPng.dylib (852) <CCBFA9A9-33C0-3189-AFE0-A77E831EEBA8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x7fff8a3fb000 -     0x7fff8a416ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.48.12) <4B7993C3-F62D-3AC1-AF92-414A0D6EED5E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x7fff8a417000 -     0x7fff8a43efff  com.apple.framework.familycontrols (4.1 - 410) <50F5A52C-8FB6-300A-977D-5CFDE4D5796B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
0x7fff8a43f000 -     0x7fff8a519fff  com.apple.backup.framework (1.4.3 - 1.4.3) <6B65C44C-7777-3331-AD9D-438D10AAC777> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
0x7fff8a51a000 -     0x7fff8a633fff  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.2.2 - 852) <1D023BCE-1FA2-3743-B449-7489BC0C5C43> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x7fff8a634000 -     0x7fff8a655fff  com.apple.Ubiquity (1.2 - 243.15) <C9A7EE77-B637-3676-B667-C0843BBB0409> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework/Versions/A/Ubiquity
0x7fff8a6e0000 -     0x7fff8a6e4ff7  com.apple.CommonPanels (1.2.5 - 94) <AAC003DE-2D6E-38B7-B66B-1F3DA91E7245> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x7fff8a6e5000 -     0x7fff8a73aff7  libTIFF.dylib (852) <0CA1662F-EB05-34DE-B9BA-0A03EC59B846> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
.....
.....
0x7fff93654000 -     0x7fff936d5fff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 707.12) <69E3EEF7-8B7B-3652-8320-B8E885370E56> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x7fff936d6000 -     0x7fff93735fff  com.apple.AE (645.6 - 645.6) <44F403C1-660A-3543-AB9C-3902E02F936F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x7fff93754000 -     0x7fff93759fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (30) <08F8731D-5961-39F1-AD00-4590321D24A9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x7fff937ef000 -     0x7fff93a24ff7  com.apple.CoreData (106.1 - 407.7) <A676E1A4-2144-376B-92B8-B450DD1D78E5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
0x7fff93a60000 -     0x7fff93abcff7  com.apple.Symbolication (1.3 - 93) <D5044687-E424-31CF-B120-667143E6B9C1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication
0x7fff93af0000 -     0x7fff93af4fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib (32.5) <DB009CD4-BB0E-3331-BBB4-A118781D193F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x7fff93af5000 -     0x7fff93af6fff  liblangid.dylib (116) <864C409D-D56B-383E-9B44-A435A47F2346> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x7fff93af7000 -     0x7fff93b95ff7  com.apple.ink.framework (10.8.2 - 150) <3D8D16A2-7E01-3EA1-B637-83A36D353308> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x7fff93fc9000 -     0x7fff94086ff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.8.0 - 4.8.0) <6CE333AE-EDDB-3768-9598-9DB38041DC55> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x7fff94087000 -     0x7fff94087fff  com.apple.vecLib (3.8 - vecLib 3.8) <6CBBFDC4-415C-3910-9558-B67176447789> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x7fff94088000 -     0x7fff940a7ff7  com.apple.ChunkingLibrary (2.0 - 133.3) <8BEC9AFB-DCAA-37E8-A5AB-24422B234ECF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/Versions/A/ChunkingLibrary
0x7fff940a8000 -     0x7fff944c5fff  FaceCoreLight (2.4.1) <DDAFFD7A-D312-3407-A010-5AEF3E17831B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/Versions/A/FaceCoreLight
0x7fff9453b000 -     0x7fff94541fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.5.2 - 2.5.2) <C713A35A-360E-36CE-AC0A-25C86A3F50CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x7fff9455e000 -     0x7fff94562fff  libpam.2.dylib (20) <C8F45864-5B58-3237-87E1-2C258A1D73B8> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
0x7fff94563000 -     0x7fff94566fff  libRadiance.dylib (852) <139962CD-21E2-3D31-9F47-D5F2D6C2C2BC> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x7fff94567000 -     0x7fff94589ff7  libxpc.dylib (140.43) <70BC645B-6952-3264-930C-C835010CCEF9> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x7fff9465e000 -     0x7fff946a8ff7  libGLU.dylib (8.10.1) <6699DEA6-9EEB-3B84-A57F-B25AE44EC584> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
0x7fff94eff000 -     0x7fff94efffff  libkeymgr.dylib (25) <CC9E3394-BE16-397F-926B-E579B60EE429> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x7fff94f00000 -     0x7fff94f0fff7  libxar.1.dylib (105) <370ED355-E516-311E-BAFD-D80633A84BE1> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
0x7fff94f4c000 -     0x7fff94f98ff7  libauto.dylib (185.4) <AD5A4CE7-CB53-313C-9FAE-673303CC2D35> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x7fff94fc1000 -     0x7fff94fc4ff7  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3) <F59367C9-C110-382B-A695-9035A6DD387E> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x7fff96120000 -     0x7fff9623892f  libobjc.A.dylib (532.2) <90D31928-F48D-3E37-874F-220A51FD9E37> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x7fff96239000 -     0x7fff96240fff  libGFXShared.dylib (8.10.1) <B4AB9480-2CDB-34F8-8D6F-F5A2CFC221B0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
0x7fff96241000 -     0x7fff96284ff7  com.apple.bom (12.0 - 192) <0BF1F2D2-3648-36B7-BE4B-551A0173209B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Versions/A/Bom
0x7fff962e1000 -     0x7fff962e2ff7  libdnsinfo.dylib (453.19) <14202FFB-C3CA-3FCC-94B0-14611BF8692D> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x7fff962e3000 -     0x7fff964cdff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.8 - 744.19) <0F7403CA-2CB8-3D0A-992B-679701DF27CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x7fff964ce000 -     0x7fff96580ff7  com.apple.LaunchServices (539.11 - 539.11) <A86F44E5-F285-3029-A5D1-00CD3C231A08> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x7fff96581000 -     0x7fff96978fff  libLAPACK.dylib (1073.4) <D632EC8B-2BA0-3853-800A-20DA00A1091C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x7fff96979000 -     0x7fff9697bfff  com.apple.securityhi (4.0 - 55002) <9B6CBA92-123F-3307-A2D7-D77A8D3BF87E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI

External Modification Summary:
    Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
        task_for_pid: 2
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
    Calls made by this process:
        task_for_pid: 0
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
    Calls made by all processes on this machine:
        task_for_pid: 4537
        thread_create: 1
        thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=142.6M resident=62.2M(44%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=80.4M(56%)
Writable regions: Total=67.3M written=236K(0%) resident=920K(1%) swapped_out=2728K(4%) unallocated=66.4M(99%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CG shared images                    128K
CoreServices                       1360K
MALLOC                             41.5M
MALLOC guard page                    48K
Memory tag=242                       12K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              9752K
VM_ALLOCATE                        16.0M
__DATA                             10.2M
__IMAGE                             528K
__LINKEDIT                         52.1M
__TEXT                             90.5M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        19.0M
shared memory                       308K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             297.6M

System Profile:
Model: iMac13,3, BootROM IM131.010A.B07, 2 processors, Intel Core i3, 3.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.10f5
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF4), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.7f4 12974, 3 service, 21 devices, 3 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST500LM012, 500.11 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1d100000 / 2
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0x1d130000 / 5
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x024f, 0x1d132000 / 9
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2412, 0x1d180000 / 3
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x1d181000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x828b, 0x1d181300 / 7
USB Device: Apple Optical USB Mouse, apple_vendor_id, 0x0304, 0x14400000 / 1
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1a100000 / 2
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8511, 0x1a110000 / 3
```

Comment: Do you have any output in the Console on the Mac that is crashing? There's not a lot to go on from that report.

Comment: @craig, the console just sais: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Sounds like you might be running into this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19531969/88111 But it's hard to tell, as that Q/A seems to suggest it's a Mavericks bug, and you're crashing on 10.8.

Comment: @craig, it's crashing on 10.8, but I packaged the app on 10.9. Could still be the case. I'll give it a try. Thanks for responding to my post.

Answer (score 0):

There could be any number of things causing the app to crash, and also multiple ways you can go about debugging it to find the culprit.

1. If using XCode to compile verify:

   `General > Deployment Info > Deployment Target > (minimum) 10.8`
2. Under Debug:

   `Breakpoints > Create Exception Breakpoint > (set break on first method)`

   (Create a standard breakpoint here as well)
3. Degbug workflow:

   `Show Disassembly While Debugging`

The third item is likely going to be of great help since we know by your crash report the last offset in `rdi`:

`0x00000000000025e5`

If you're not using XCode you can use any debugger or disassembler to figure out what is at that offet — which will likely lead you straight to the source of your crash.