# Issues with Python update on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7

So, yesterday I could run python scripts just fine. I also had numpy installed and tested on my system. From here, I proceeded to install opencv on my Mac following this [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/).

Afterwards, I tested it and it worked fine. Then I installed [pyOSC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOSC).

Then I proceeded to use two example scripts to test that it was working fine, and it was.

Then, I updated python on my system, and now it can't find OSC and numpy whenever I try to call them (from the python interpreter or another script). When I run `pip list` I can see that they're still installed. I'm pretty sure this is the root of the issue, I'm just not sure how to fix it without uninstalling and re-installing everything.

Any Ideas? Currently running python 2.7

**EDIT** I had the version of python that came with the system and I downloaded the new version of python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/) because I was having issues with [segmentation fault 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531969/segmentation-fault-11-in-os-x) error.

Comment: Please state how you originally installed python (is it the system one?) and how you "updated python".

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I figured it out.

I used `type -a python` to see all versions I had of python. 
Weirdly enough, I had the Mac System version as `/usr/bin/python` and then I had two entries under `/usr/local/bin/python`. I deleted both of these and now everything is working properly.

Comment: For future reference, you may wish to consider the anaconda python distribution. One advantage, aside from many precompiled packages and enviromenting system, is isolating you working python from the system python.