# Python segmentation fault 11 on OpenNI module import -- issues with Homebrew boost and python?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, boost, homebrew, openni

I am running a homebrew version of python on OSX 10.9: Maverick.

**Short version:**

I am experiencing a `Python segmentation fault 11` when I try to import an OpenNI module into python. I have tried renaming my `readline.so` file as suggested in the link below, so I am assuming this is a different problem:

[Python crashing when running two commands (Segmentation Fault: 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158381/python-crashing-when-running-two-commands-segmentation-fault-11)

I am wondering if this might be an issue with my homebrew boost install not linking to the correct version of python. Though I cannot seem to fix it and very well may be barking up the wrong tree.

**Very long version:**

I've been trying to to install the PyOpenNI python module following directions from this site:
http://www.justinfx.com/2012/06/21/getting-started-with-xbox-360-kinect-on-osx/

Instead of manually installing OpenNI, NITE, and the Sensor Kinect drivers as specified on that link, I used brew versions I found here:
https://github.com/totakke/homebrew-openni

Everything seems to have worked fine until I reached the last step, installing PyOpenNI. I ran into a CMake error when creating the make file; it did not find the OpenNI library and include directories. I manually put these in the CMakeCache.txt file and installation seemed to work fine after that.

Once I tried to to import the openni module in a python shell, I got:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

Googling this for a bit, some people suggested it was a Boost error, having installed to the Mac build of Python instead of the Homebrew version. 
[Homebrew + Python on mac os x 10.8: Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread importing mapnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678153/homebrew-python-on-mac-os-x-10-8-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-cu)

Running `otool -L $(brew list boost | grep 'python.*.dylib')` output suggested this was the case:

Line of interest:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.5)
```

Full output:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib:
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.5)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/lib/libboost_python.dylib:
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.5)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

I uninstalled boost and reinstalled it with `brew install boost --build-from-source`

Funny thing is, after installing, it gave this warning:

```
The Boost bottle's module will not import into a Homebrew-installed Python.
If you use the Boost Python module then please:
  brew install boost --build-from-source
```

which is obviously funny since I just did that. Running `otool` again:

Line of interest:

```
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
```

Full output:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib:
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/lib/libboost_python.dylib:
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

So now it seems to point to a different python framework directory, but seems like it is still not the Homebrew python framework directory.

Am I correct in this assessment that boost is still not linking to the homebrew version of python? Could this be causing the Segmentation fault 11, or is that caused by something else entirely?

Comment: Maybe it'll help someone—I've read in some Homebrew issue's comments that segmentation fault usually means wrong Python binary. For example, something was build against system python but is run against brewed python.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is late but it might be helpful to someone as it was to me. Apparently the solution to this was posted by [akakcolin](https://github.com/jmendeth/PyOpenNI/issues/33#issuecomment-58757884) as an answer to one of the issues related to PyOpenNI on Github.

1. Rebuild homebrew Python:

   `brew update` then `brew doctor`

   `brew rm python`

   `brew install python --force --install-lib --install-headers --install-data --verbose`
2. Symlink:

   `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.x/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib /usr/local/lib/` (pay attention to the version of python you are using)
3. cmake and make:

   `cmake ../PyOpenNI` you might have to specify `-D OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIR`

   `make`

This worked for me with Python 2.7.10 and boost (with boost-python) 1.58.0